# Can "behave" handle the settings in /etc/host file?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, python-behave, dnsmasq

On ubuntu 16.0.4, I am trying to run a behave script where the testing site, "https://dev-mock-domain.xyz.com", is of a private IP. So far, I have the IP value setup in my /etc/hosts file. And when I was to run such command: "curl -k -v https://dev-mock-domain.xyz.com" on ubuntu, it was able to get the host resolved.
But if I was to run my behave automation script on the same host, it just could not resolve the domain name.  Any ideas ? Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the directory structure of your framework. 
Generally, there could be such a structure:

```
Framwork 
|--features
|--resources/testVM/etc_hbost
```

etc_host file should contain your ip hostname mapping. e.g:

```
192.168.20.01 hostname
```

Comment: `/etc/hosts` is a system file used by standard system libraries.  Unless the python framework replaces those library calls dropping a replacement in like that can't work.

Comment: i assumed, this. 
To go one step further below  but still in the resources folder, i would expect a shell script that contains configuration for etc_host.